# Is this dataset suitable for regression discontinuity?

Tags: panel-data, regression-discontinuity

I have a panel following 300 units in which the treatment variable $D$ depends on a continuous running variable $R$. Concretely, $D=1$ if $R>=0$ and $D=0$ if $R<0$. Despite having a low number of units, each of them is observed over time for a quite lengthy period. Additionally, the treatment and running variable are "decided" at $t=1$ and remained fixed afterward for each unit. That is, for each unit, either $D=1$ or $D=0$ for all $t$. This implies that using fixed effects would vanish my coefficient for $D$. Finally, my dataset also contains an outcome categorical variable $y$ which changes with time. For reference, a simplified version of my data with two units and 30 periods looks like this:

| Id | $t$ | $D$ | $R$ | $y$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.05 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0.05 | 2 |
| $\dots$ | $\dots$ | $\dots$ | $\dots$ | $\dots$ |
| 1 | 30 | 1 | 0.05 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | -0.05 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | -0.05 | 2 |
| $\dots$ | $\dots$ | $\dots$ | $\dots$ | $\dots$ |
| 2 | 30 | 0 | -0.05 | 1 |

I want to examine the effect of $D$ on $y$, as I have good theoretical grounds to believe that there is a causal association going on. However, I am quite unfamiliar with Regression Discontunity and was wondering whether my dataset is suitable for this kind of design. In particular, I was wondering how using RD here would differ from using RD on a panel in which $R$ (and hence $D$) also changes with $t$. I was also told that the RD estimator is quite "data hungry" and so lots of data are needed for it to work. Since each unit is observed a lot of times, I do have a lot of observations but not a lot of variation in my running variable. Would this be a potential issue? Finally, I would be very grateful if you could direct me to any papers that tackle a similar dataset to the one I am outlining here.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Regression discontinuity is useful when there is some exogenous event or attribute that can be used to identify an effect. Knowing whether RD is appropriate here is determined by whether D is an exogenous attribute. It makes sense that D is time-invariant for an RD design, but that's not the important feature for determining whether RD is appropriate. You'll want to look at D and be able to say that the only difference between your two groups (D==0 and D==1) with relevance to y is the status of D. If there is any other variable (z) that can effect both D and y, RD would not be appropriate.

It is quite difficult to identify a "quasi-experimental" treatment that satisfies the requirements for an RD design, so you'll want to think carefully about whether D is truly exogenously assigned.

You'll also want to think more about how y varies. Do you expect y to increase or decrease at a different rate over the panel between your D groups? Or do you expect there to simply be a different average value between D groups?

If y has different expected growth trajectories for D groups, you could look into running a growth model, which would use an interaction between t and D.

If D were time-variant, it would be unlikely to be appropriate for RD, as D's status would need to be exogenous over the repeated measures. I can't think of a situation like that (but I could be wrong). You could consider a fixed-effects model with year dummies, though.